# Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in SQLContext.class refers to type Logging in package org.apache.spark which is not available

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

When I complied a scala file used IntelliJ IDEA, the following error showed.

**Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in SQLContext.class refers to type Logging in package org.apache.spark which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SQLContext.class.**

Attention: the error happened when I add the spark-sql into the pom.xml file. Is it the version problem?

my pom.xml is：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>cn.zhangyitian.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>sparkProject2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Specifies the configuration file of the assembly plugin -->
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you tried using same version of spark, In case of spark-core_2.10 use version as 1.6.2

Comment: Oh, Thanks, it worked. I have tried a lot of times the other way but forgot the version of spark-core.

Comment: If this helped you can accept as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the same version of spark for all the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace this with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can use `Spark 2.1.0` in all dependencies

Comment: Seems to be intermittent. After a a while this issue disappeared where I was.